# How can I manage a snap application permissions using command line?

Tags: command-line, permissions, gnome-terminal, snap

How can I manage, i.e., enable/disable permissions for a snap application through command line via terminal.

For eg. I have installed Opera using snap, and I can manage its various permissions using Software, but I wanted to manage them using command line.

[image: Permissions in Software]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through interfaces (plugs/slots)

```
snap connections opera
```

You can manually control connection:

```
snap connect <snap>:<plug interface> <snap>:<slot interface>
snap disconnect <snap>:<plug interface> <snap>:<slot interface>
```

References:

- https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-guide-to-snap-permissions-and-interfaces
- https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-interfaces
- https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management